# SharePoint public url is not retrieve but load balancer url is retrieved using sharepoiont OM

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a web site that is configure by access mapping point for load balancer url "http://xyz:90" , now we publish the web site on internet with public url "http://compnyname"  and the ISA is configure to point to "http://xyz:90" ,The problem is in code I am using SPContext.Current.Web.URL to build URL for web site visitor and send mail but it retrieve "http://xyz:90" not "http://compnyname"

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can't know what ISA is going to do, you need to look at Alternate Access Mappings (AAM) in the Central Admin.